# Null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, null

I am trying to display the elements of my ArrayList in an action listener method by calling a printlibrary method from another class(library). I keep getting a null pointer exception at this line                                                                 `library.addItem(libraryItem);` I dont understand how to fix this 
I have already used validation in the form of an if statement to see if library is null and    a                                                                                          system.out to see if the button action listner is actually working and the button does work

```
        { 

    {System.out.println("hello world");
        String t = title.getText();     
        int y = Integer.parseInt(year.getText());
        int q = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()); 

                if(library != null)
                {
        LibraryItem libraryItem = new LibraryItem(t,y,q);
        library.addItem(libraryItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("its null");
                }


library.printLibrary();
    }
```

HERE IS THE REST OF MY LIBRARYFRAME CLASS!!!

```
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import java.awt.GridLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;  
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import javax.swing.JTextField;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;



   public class LibraryFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {
     JLabel label, label2, label3;
     JTextField title, year, quantity;
     JButton button, button2;

      private Library library; 



public LibraryFrame()
{
  this.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,10,10)); //2nd set of co-ord (10,10) is for row and coloumn spacing.

   label = new JLabel("Title");
   title = new JTextField(20);

   label2 = new JLabel("Year");
   year = new JTextField(20);

   label3 = new JLabel("Quantity");
   quantity = new JTextField(20);

   button = new JButton("Add");
   button2 = new JButton("Search");
   button.addActionListener(this);


  this.add(label);
  this.add(title);
  this.add(label2);
  this.add(year);
  this.add(label3);
  this.add(quantity);
  this.add(button);
  this.add(button2); 

}   


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
{ 



    {System.out.println("hello world");
        String t = title.getText();     
        int y = Integer.parseInt(year.getText());
        int q = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()); 

                if(library != null)
                {
        LibraryItem libraryItem = new LibraryItem(t,y,q);
        library.addItem(libraryItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("its null");
                }


library.printLibrary();
    }

}







public static void main (String args[])
{

    LibraryFrame frame = new LibraryFrame();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);




}

}
```

HERE IS MY LIBRARY CLASS

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;


              public class Library {

         private ArrayList<LibraryItem> items;




public Library()
{
    items = new ArrayList<LibraryItem>();
}



public void addItem(LibraryItem newItem)
{
    items.add(newItem);



}

public LibraryItem searchForItem (String name)

{
    for(LibraryItem searchForItem: items)
    {
        if(searchForItem.getName().equals(name) )

    return searchForItem;


}
    return null;
}

public void printLibrary()
{


    for(int i = 0; i< items.size(); i++)
    {

        System.out.println(items.get(i));
    }


}
```

}

HERE IS MY LIBRARY ITEM CLASS`

```
public class LibraryItem 
{

    private String name;
    private int year, quantity;

       LibraryItem(String nameIn, int yearIn, int quantityIn)
       {
           name = nameIn;
           year = yearIn;
           quantity = quantityIn;



       }



    public boolean rent()
    {


        if(quantity > 0) 

        {
             quantity--;

        }
          return true;
    }






                   public String toString()
            {
                return name + " " +"has"+ " " +quantity+ "available";


                }

                  public String getName()
            {
                  return name;

            }


             public int getQuantity()
          {

            return quantity;
         }

              public int getYear()
            {

                  return year;
             }


   }
```

HERE IS MY MEMBER CLASS `

```
                   public class Member 
           {

     private String name ;
        private int dayOfBirth, monthOfBirth, yearOfBirth;



    Member(String nameIn, int dayOfBirthIn, int monthOfBirthIn, int yearOfBirthIn)
    {
       name = nameIn;
       dayOfBirth = dayOfBirthIn;
       monthOfBirth = monthOfBirthIn;
       yearOfBirth = yearOfBirthIn;



   }



          public String toString ()
    {
    return name + " " +dayOfBirth+ " " +monthOfBirth+ " " +yearOfBirth;

      }




}
```

`

Comment: is your `library` not `null`?

Comment: Did you try the debugger? Also, please see how unorganized the code looks in your question and make it better. Finally, try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: are you sure t,y and q aren't null? what about using a debugger?

Comment: Please only post well formatted code, since the easier it is to read your code, the easier it is for us to understand it and help you. Please read the help section to see how to have your posted code retain its formatting. Your goal when asking a question should be to make it as easy as possible for volunteers here to be able to help you.

Comment: Please first indent you code and use proper grammer. If you don't care to make up a good question why should we bother giving a good answer?

Comment: @user1631616 he does check if library is null, and if so doesn't use it.

Comment: @aoeu What about the fact that English is not everyone's native language?

Comment: @Aquillo learn English :)

Comment: ouch. At least learn code formatting. That much is universal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to assign library to anything before you try to use it.

Comment: Thanks mate can't believe I didn't see that your a life saver!

Comment: No problem.  I wrote this a while back because we kept seeing similar questions on irc:  http://www.antwerkz.com/dealing-with-nullpointerexceptions/